# How to divide an observable collection equally

Tags: c#

I would like to split the `tar' collection evenly. I have 6 separate collections and I would like to populate them across 6 list evenly no matter the size of the collection
e.g if there are 23 items the 6 list should be 4,4,4,4,4 and the last 3 or 24: 4,4,4,4,4 and 4

```
ObservableCollection<test> tar = new ObservableCollection<test>();
        tar.Add(new test { name="a"});
        tar.Add(new test { name = "b" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "c" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "d" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "e" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "f" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "g" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "h" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "i" });
        tar.Add(new test { name="ae"});
        tar.Add(new test { name = "br" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "cwr" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "dt" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "ef" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "ff" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "fg" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "hg" });
        tar.Add(new test { name = "ie" });
```

I have tried this function that I found only but not sure how to access the groups.

```
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<test>> Split(ObservableCollection<test> collection, int splitBy = 3)
    {

        var result = collection
                   .Select((x, i) => new { index = i, item = x })
                   .GroupBy(x => x.index / splitBy, x => x.item)
                   .Select(g => new ObservableCollection<test>(g));
        return new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<test>>(result);
    }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Will Do. I am not familiar with IEnumerables But I will try converting it to ObservableCOLLECTION

Comment: [morelinq:  Batch](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)

Comment: I already tried using your input with my extension and it works because ObservableCollection is a Collection and Collection implements IEnumerable. No conversion should be needed. If you need any help using the code, I can assist with that too.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation sounds a lot like a Batch extension I wrote.
It takes a collection and returns a new collection of those items split into batches of a specified size. The last batch in the returned collection will have the left over items, so it won't have as many items as the rest, you could modify this code to do that, and I will work on it now too (edit below).

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items, int size)
{
    return items.Batch(size, x => x);
}

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Batch<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> items, int size, 
    Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> selector)
{
    if (items == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(items));
    if (size <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));
    if (selector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));

    using (var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var taken = 0;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return selector(items.Skip(taken)
                .Take(size));
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                    break;
            taken += size;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The below modifications to the Batch extension work for me. You may want to implement it a different way depending on how you want it to populate the last batch. The way I have done it uses the default value of TSource, which for you is test which defaults as null.

```
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    IEnumerable<TSource> batch;
    batch = items.Skip(taken).Take(size);
    var count = items.Count();
    if (taken + size >= count)
        batch = batch.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, count - taken)
            .Select(i => default(TSource)));
    yield return selector(batch);
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            break;
    taken += size;
}
```